# How to include file in subdomain from main domain

Tags: php, html

I have one main domain and one subdomain example main domain have.

`header.php --> index.php --> footer.php` and sub domain have `index.php` I want to include the main domain `index.php` in subdomain for example like

```
include '../index.php';
include '../public_html/home/xxxxx/index.php';
```

but its not working. Now I want to include `header.php` from main domain in `index.php` which is in sub domain. By using the include function I get the error failed to open stream: No such file or directory in `/home/content/xx/xxx/xxxx/xxx/`

I know that this error occurs when a file does not exists on the given mentioned path, but how can I include a file from main domain to subdomain? thank you in advance

Comment: You need to understand why is file not found. I also suppose that in subdomain `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]` is not the same as in main domain, so it can cause this error too.

Comment: You're mixing concepts like subdomains with paths here. The two are not necessarily related. Does the file actually exist in the path you specify?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the full patch.Without any problem

```
 define("URLSITEPATH1",(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]");
include URLSITEPATH1.'/index.php';
include URLSITEPATH1.'/YourPatch/index.php';
```